# JsonRpcEngine: Response has no error or result for request:

Tags: tokens, json-rpc, deploy

I tried to deploy my smart contract on bsc testnet but it failed. Please explain where it went wrong. [image]

Comment: There isn't enough information to provide a helpful answer. It could be the transaction had a low fee and it got stuck and timed out without providing more details. Did you got a transaction hash? Did you check in a block explorer your address for pending transactions?